# Как программно нажать кнопку при помощи Java?

Tags: java

Добрый день. Подскажите, как программно ввести логин и пароль, а затем их подтвердить, программно нажав кнопку с использованием Java. Есть ряд форумов - хочется работать со всеми через один интерфейс.

Comment: спасибо почитаю. Возможно там и есть решение всех проблем и с форумов запросы собирать и голосовать (логика проста, а вот ручек не хватает (((). Спасибо за оперативность.

Comment: если вам очень надо я бы посоветовал повесить на компе прокси и фильтровать запросы до этих сайтов. парсить их контент и добавлять его к нужному вам шаблону.

Answer (score 2):

Программно нажать кнопку из явы можно, правда не понимаю как это вам поможет, ибо подход к решению проблемы, на мой взгляд, должен быть иной. Прав Nofate, про взаимодействие с помощью HTTP.

Но если все-таки не послушаете - почитайте в документации, или на форумах про класс java.awt.Robot. Он позволяет программно управлять мышью и клавиатурой, а также считывать информацию с экрана.

Comment: Конечно послушаю )). Но с библиотекой решение как-то ближе и родней и управляемей - может это пока..

Answer (score 1):

В первой части книги Хорстманна Java 2. Даются примеры использования как уже писали выше  java.awt.Robot Попробуйте. Там достаточно всё прозначно и нетрудно

Answer (score 0):

Если нажимать кнопки и заполнять поля на сайтах, то читать про HttpRequest или руками формировать GET и POST запросы к формам на сайтах (там ничего сложного на самом деле нет).